# how to iterate a map with its key/value with a count just like "i ++" in the "for" statement

Tags: go

I am using go language and I want to iterate a map with its keys and values all over a map, 
at the same time, I also want to count the number of items in the map

I tried this:

```
  for i := 0; k,v := range map; i++ { }
```

I just want to know if `for ...` range statement can work with `i++` which is  usual part of 
`for` statement

Answer (score 3):

As you must have discovered when you tried it, that doesn't work.  You have to just spell it out:

```
i := 0
for k, v := range someMap {
    //...
    i++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [range clause](http://golang.org/ref/spec#RangeClause) of the [for statement](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) doesn't allow this. You have to write, for example:

```
var i int
for k, v := range myMap {
        whatever()
        i++
}
```

Note that if you don't mutate the map while iterating over it then

```
i == len(myMap)
```

is true afterwards.